# View Cart works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE

Tags: internet-explorer, paypal, shopping-cart

I have PayPal Add to Cart and View Cart buttons on a website I'm building. Add to Cart works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE. View Cart works in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. I'm using IE 10 on Windows 7, with Wampserver proving a localhost. The PayPal functions are executed for real, not using a sandbox, with genuine PayPal accounts. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using or the site you're testing this on?

Comment: Here's the relevant fragment. As I said, I only have a problem with IE.

Comment: <form target="_blank" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">

<input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="business" value="charlie.lewis@brianwalsholdbooksandirishbooks.co.uk">

<input target="_top" type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/BWB/index.html">

<button class="NavigationViewCartMenuEntry" name='submit' type='submit' title='Click to look at your PayPal shopping basket' alt='Click to look at your PayPal shopping basket'>Basket</button>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sulalor@eircom.net">
<input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="localhost/BWB/index.html">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_viewcart_LG.gif" border="0" 
name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Using a localhost site may cause a little problem with the return to your site but it shouldn't prevent it from working at all.